# Counting $\pm 1$ and $0$'s in the character tables of $\frak{S}_n$

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, enumerative-combinatorics

Let $\chi_{\mu}^{\lambda}$ denote a value of an irreducible character of the symmetric group $\frak{S}_n$, where $\mu, \lambda\vdash n$. When $\mu=(n)$, then it's known that
$$\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}\chi_{\mu}^{\lambda}=\delta_\text{odd}(n).$$

I like to ask:

> **QUESTION 1.** Is there a formula for the enumeration (cardinality) of $a_n=\#\{\lambda\vdash n: \chi_{(n)}^{\lambda}=0\}$? How about $b_n=\#\{\lambda\vdash n: \chi_{(n)}^{\lambda}=1\}$ or $c_n=\#\{\lambda\vdash n: \chi_{(n)}^{\lambda}=-1\}$?

Encouraged by Mark Wildom's prompt/neat [reply](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403791/counting-pm-1-and-0s-in-the-character-tables#comment1034199_403791), I like to update the question to counting all $0$'s.

> **QUESTION 2.** How about the cardinality (or generating function) of the below?
> $$d_n=\#\{(\lambda,\mu): \lambda\vdash n, \mu\vdash n, \chi_{\mu}^{\lambda}=0\}.$$

Comment: You can enumerate these sets very easily using the Murnaghan--Nakayama rule to compute the character values: $\chi^\lambda_{(n)}$ is non-zero if and only if $\lambda$ is a hook partition of the form $(n-k,1^k)$, and in this case the character value is $(-1)^k$.

Comment: @MarkWildon: Thank you.

Comment: An exact answer is likely to be hopeless. For a partial result, see https://www.armiller.org/CharacterZeros.pdf. (This paper appeared in *Math. Z.* in 2014.) A necessary condition for $\chi_\mu^\lambda\neq 0$ is that the $q$-hook product $\prod_{u\in\lambda}(1-q^{h(u)})$ is divisible (in $\mathbb{Z}[q]$) by $\prod_{i=1}^{\ell(\mu)}(1-q^{\mu_i})$. See EC2, Exercise 7.60.

Comment: @RichardStanley: I appreciate this informative reply despite the lack of a closed form.

Comment: A side question related to my previous comment: let $f(n)$ be the fraction of pairs $(\lambda,\mu)$ of partitions of $n$ such that $\prod_{u\in\lambda} (1-q^{h(u)})$ is divisible by $\prod_{i=1}^{\ell((\mu)}(1-q^{\mu_i})$. Does $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)$ exist? If so, what is its value? It looks like it might be around $3/4$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is an open problem to determine how many of the entries of the character table are zero — or, indeed whether the proportion of zeros tends to a positive constant, or to zero.   One should be careful about the exact problem considered:  if a character is picked at random, and a group element is picked at random (so $p(n)$ choices for the character and $n!$ choices for the group element) then almost all entries are zero.  This is the partial result mentioned in Stanley's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403791/counting-pm-1-and-0s-in-the-character-tables#comment1034207_403791) to the question.  However this is a very different statistic from picking the character at random and a conjugacy class at random (the problem in the question).  Miller ([On parity and characters of symmetric groups](https://www.armiller.org/Parity.pdf)) has done some numerics on this (see Table 3), and conjectured that almost all values were multiples of any given number $d$.  This last conjecture has been established for all prime numbers $d$, in the work of Peluse ([On even entries in the character table of the symmetric group](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.06652)) and Peluse and Soundararajan ([Almost all entries in the character table of the symmetric group are multiples of any given prime](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.12410)) (consequently, $\pm 1$ — or indeed any fixed non-zero integer — appears with density zero in the character table).  As for zero entries, the best lower bound that I know (which follows from these ideas of using Murnaghan—Nakayama and the structure of random partitions) is that at least a proportion $c/\log n$ of the entries are zero.

Comment: I'm grateful for further details and references!

Answer (score 2):

Since this boils down to the famous Murnaghan–Nakayama rule,
I like to advertise an alternative formula due to Adin and Roichman,

Ron M. Adin and Yuval Roichman. [Matrices, characters and descents](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2014.11.028). Linear Algebra and its Applications, 469:381–418, March 2015.

It was stated in a more explicit manner by Athanasiadis ([Power sum expansion of chromatic quasisymmetric functions](http://dx.doi.org/10.37236/4761)); see
the exact formula and reference here: http://symmetricfunctions.com/gessel.htm#gesselPowerSum.
(The statement is much more general, but for your application, just plug in a Schur function for $X(x)$. Its expansion in Gessel quasisymmetric functions is well-known.)

Comment: Could you say what exactly follows from this alternative for Question 2? (the number of zeros in the character table)

Comment: @Lucia I have not used this formula that much, but it has some advantages. For example, it generalizes to quasisymmetric functions (for getting the quasisymmetric power-sum expansion of Gessel quasisymmetric functions, for example).

Comment: @PerAlexandersson: Thank you for this information. Although I am not sure what this means to the given problems at hand.